# How to automatically add comments when creating a CSS rule in PhpStorm/WebStorm

Tags: css, ide, coding-style, phpstorm, webstorm

What I am trying to achieve is this:

When creating a new CSS rule, add a series of comments, for instance:

```
.class_name {
   /* Comment one */
   /* Comment two */
   /* Comment three */
   /* and son on... */
}
```

I tried looking inside the settings: `Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates` but nothing.

Nothing in `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Style Sheets > CSS` either.

If this is not possible via `settings`, is there any way to create a keymap?

Comment: There is no option to insert any comments or customize newly created CSS selector rule / anything like that in CSS files as fas as I'm aware. The best I may offer is to use Live Templates to insert a custom code snippet where you need it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html

Comment: @LazyOne thank you for pointing that, I've managed to achieve this with a small command. These are the steps I followed:

Go to:

`File > Settings > Editor > Live Templates`

* Click de Plus(+) button in the upper right corner
* Template Group
* And name the group CSS
* Then click the plus sight again, and Live Template
* Abbreviation: in my case I named 'cc'
* Gave a description
* And in the template text I put the desire text, in my case a series of comments
* Applicable in: Declaration block
* Done!

Thank you @LazyOne :)